# Create/Update table in MS Access dynamically

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

EDIT:

Here's what I have: An Access database made up of 3 tables linked from SQL server. I need to create a new table in this database by querying the 3 source tables. Here are examples of the 3 tables I'm using:

```
PlanTable1
+------+------+------+------+---------+---------+
| Key1 | Key2 | Key3 | Key4 |  PName  | MainKey |
+------+------+------+------+---------+---------+
|   53 |    1 |    5 |   -1 | Bikes   |  536681 |
|   53 |   99 |   -1 |   -1 | Drinks  |  536682 |
|   53 |   66 |   68 |   -1 | Balls   |  536683 |
+------+------+------+------+---------+---------+

SpTable
+----+---------+---------+
| ID | MainKey | SpName  |
+----+---------+---------+
| 10 |  536681 | Wing1   |
| 11 |  536682 | Wing2   |
| 12 |  536683 | Wing3   |
+----+---------+---------+

LocTable
+-------+-------------+--------------+
| LocID | CenterState |  CenterCity  |
+--- ---+-------------+--------------+
| 10    | IN          | Indianapolis |
| 11    | OH          | Columbus     |
| 12    | IL          | Chicago      |
+-------+-------------+--------------+
```

You can see the relationships between the tables. The NewMasterTable I need to create based off of these will look something like this:

```
NewMasterTable
+-------+--------+-------------+------+--------------+-------+-------+-------+
| LocID | PName  | CenterState | Key4 |  CenterCity  | Wing1 | Wing2 | Wing3 |
+-------+--------+-------------+------+--------------+-------+-------+-------+
| 10    | Bikes  | IN          |   -1 | Indianapolis |     1 |     0 |     0 |
| 11    | Drinks | OH          |   -1 | Columbus     |     0 |     1 |     0 |
| 12    | Balls  | IL          |   -1 | Chicago      |     0 |     0 |     1 |
+-------+--------+-------------+------+--------------+-------+-------+-------+
```

The hard part for me is making this new table dynamic. In the future, rows may be added to the source tables. I need my NewMasterTable to reflect any changes/additions to the source. How do I go about building the NewMasterTable as described? Does this make any sort of sense?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. I would urge you to read your question and ask yourself if you think you would be able to answer this based solely on the information provided here. It isn't even clear what the question is. Here is a great place to start improving this question. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Understood. Let me re-work my question.

Comment: Sean summed it up nicely, but in particular you say the id column "will constantly change".  What, precisely, will change?  The column value for each row?  The number of rows?  This really requires an explanation for its own sake, but normally ID columns do not change for each row.  It goes against the entire concept of why they are called ID columns, so you should also explain how your table differs from common relational database models.

Comment: @C Perkins As I said before I'll re-work and edit my question for clarity. In the meantime, I can address your question: The the number of rows in that "ID" column may increase in the future.

Comment: I don't mean to question your requirements, but what you show and describe sounds more like a query rather than a table. The NewMasterTable could be generated using only queries (with either embedded sub-queries or intermediate saved queries).  A query will by its nature include new records and will always return the latest values from the source. So now the question becomes whether you really need to persist the information in a separate table? Will you be adding columns to the new table with augmented data for each row? Can source rows also be deleted--what happens to those in the new table?

Comment: If it matters, the NewMasterTable will also be a synched sharepoint list. I couldn't find a way to do this without creating an actual table.

Comment: You'll see I posted an answer which I hope helps point you in the right direction, but the more detail I felt compelled to include, the more I realized that this question is too broad for a single Stack Overflow question.  Perhaps this was a better question for the [Database Administrators](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) forum?  If you have question with any particular step that I mentioned, it would be best to research it separately, then if needed post another question about that one specific issue.  Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

Since an Access table is a necessary requirement, then probably the only way to go about it is to create a set of Update and Insert queries that are executed periodically.  There is no built-in "dynamic" feature of Access that will monitor and update the table.

First, create the table.  You could either 1) do this manually from scratch by defining the columns and constraints yourself, or 2) create a make-table query (i.e. SELECT... INTO) that generates most of the schema, then add any additional columns, edit necessary details and add appropriate indexes.

Define and save Update and Insert (and optional Delete) queries to keep the table synced.  I'm not sharing actual code here, because that goes beyond your primary issue I think and requires specifics that you need to define.  Due to some ambiguity with your key values (the field names and sample data still are not sufficient to reveal precise relationships and constraints), it is likely that you'll need multiple Update statements.

- In particular, the "Wing" columns will likely require a transform statement.
- You may not be able to update all columns appropriately using a single query.  I recommend not trying to force such an "artificial" requirement.  Multiple queries can actually be easier to understand and maintain.
- In the event that you experience "query is not updateable" errors, you may need to define other "temporary" tables with appropriate indexes, into which you do initial inserts from the linked tables, then subsequent queries to update your master table from those.

Finally, and I think this is the key to solving your problem, you need to **define some Access form (or other code) that periodically runs your set of "sync" queries**.  Access forms have a [Timer Interval] property and corresponding Timer event that fires periodically.  Add VBA code in the Form_Timer sub that runs all your queries.  I would suggest "wrapping" such VBA in a transaction and adding appropriate error handling and error logging, etc.